# How do you intercept a keyboard interrupt (CTRL-C) in Jython?

Tags: java, jvm, jython, signal-handling

This is what I've tried...

```
from sun.misc import Signal
from sun.misc import SignalHandler

class InterruptHandler(SignalHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print "Shutting down server..."


Signal.handle(Signal("INT"),InterruptHandler())
```

It's based on this http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue043.html, but evidently I'm missing something.

Comment: For what it's worth, try catch doesn't seem to work either.  It appears that the python vm thread catches the interrupt instead of the script.

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like a bug in Jython](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1313).  There are some workarounds given there.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem before. This is how I get it resolved.

First, register a signal handler in your Jython script by:

```
import signal
def intHandler(signum, frame):
    print "Shutting down.."
    System.exit(1)

# Set the signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, intHandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, intHandler)
```

This will register the signal handler for the Jython script to handle CTRL+C keyboard input.

However, the default console class org.python.util.JLineConsole treats ctrl+C as a normal character inputs.

So, Secondly - need to change the python.console to an alternative console class org.python.core.PlainConsole by either change the Jython property:

```
python.console=org.python.core.PlainConsole
```

or add the jvm argument:

```
-Dpython.console=org.python.core.PlainConsole
```

This will help you to shutdown the program after CTRL+C is pressed.